# Suddenly my browsers have become very slow

Tags: debian, browser, lag

I have decide to include `uvcvideo` on `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` for privacy, and after reboot the notebook my browsers - Chromium and Firefox - started to lag a lot. Open new tabs, rolling pages, open sites becomes very slow. I even have typing lag. So I decided remove `uvcvideo` from the blacklist, reboot the machine and aparently things come back to normal... but sometimes when I turn on my notebook the browser return to the same slow state. They just come back to normal if I clean all the history of browser with Bleachbit **and** reboot the machine.

Sometimes I turn on my machine and things works normal. Sometimes don't. And the only change I done on my system was the mencioned above.

I'm using Debian 9 (minimal install with XFCE).

**Edit**: I have decided to re-install Chromium. I `--purge` the package as a root and delete the `~/.config/chromium/` file. Let's see if this solve the problem. I need some reboots and hours of use to say if this works. Let's pray.

**Edit 2**: Works. The browser returns to his normal state. And guess what? When I decide to add the webcam driver again, the browser becomes very slow. I had to do all the job again deleting the Chromium file and so on.

Comment: No, because I realize that the problem might be other. New problem, new question, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable camera driver without affect my system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435889/how-to-disable-camera-driver-without-affect-my-system)